# Memory-mapped files -> Checking for duplicate file names

Tags: c#, .net, memory-mapped-files

Working on an app that will use memory-mapped files for some inter-(or is it intra?)application communication, and I want to make sure when I randomly generate a memory-mapped memory-only file, I don't accidentally generate or get a duplicate that already exists (that ultra-rare case when the planets align and something like that might happen). Any ideas on how to prevent that? System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles does not appear to have a File.Exists() method...I guess I could try OpenOrCreate() and deal with any access violations, etc., but this would be getting nasty quick.

Comment: It's interprocess. First you create a file -- make sure it's unique. Then you memory map it. So I don't understand the problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Comment: Memory mapping to an actual file is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Using `File.Exists()` wouldn't be concurrency-safe anyway.

The best thing to do: base a Filename on a Guid.

Comment: Wish I could, but a GUID is too large to send via SendMessage() to tell the other process to open. Currently thinking of using part of a DateTime for uniqueness, and crossing my fingers.

Comment: @user978122 Then use TWO SendMessage (with different msg id)! The other party waits for both "parts" of the message.

Comment: Is increasing the complexity of the program...and complexity is bad! ^_^

Comment: Doesn't a Guid fit into the two message params on 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

[From: Programming Memory-Mapped Files with the .NET Framework - CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138290/Programming-Memory-Mapped-Files-with-the-NET-Frame)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = "NetMMFSingle";

    // Create named MMF
    try
    {
        var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(name, 1);
    } catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instance already running...");
        return;
    }

    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();

    // Your real code follows...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can prevent a naming conflict by using a unique name for your file, such as your company name, or your application name, or both.  No other app is going to have those in the file name.  If you're worried about two copies of the same app, then you can simply open the file in Create only mode, rather than Create or Open.